# Open Microsoft.practices.EnterpriseLibrary database with just a connection string

Tags: database, enterprise-library, database-connection, connection-string

I am using the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary Database tools and I'm having trouble creating a new database using *just* the connection string information.

Ideally I would like to do the following:

```
Database dbEngine = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(
    "Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
```

Is it possible to create a database using just the connection string?

If so, how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can also do

```
Database mydb = new EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql.SqlDatabase("connection string here");
```

and you'll retain the versatility of the Database object, but create it with a connection string.

Answer (score 5):

I am building a connection string on the fly dynamically with the following where ConnectionString is in my .config

```
     Database configdb = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("ConnectionString");

                DbConnectionStringBuilder sb = configdb.DbProviderFactory.CreateConnectionStringBuilder();

                // Set the Connection String fields.

                sb["Data Source"] = targetServer; 
                sb["Initial Catalog"] = targetDb; 
                sb["User ID"] = username;
                sb["Password"] = password;
                sb["Connect Timeout"] = dbTimeout;

                GenericDatabase newDb = new GenericDatabase(sb.ToString(), configdb.DbProviderFactory);
Database db = newDb;
```

Answer (score 0):

Er... That's because CreateDatabase expects the *name* of a connection string (as specified in your app's config file), not the connection string itself.

Comment: That was just an example of what I was attempting to do, I wondered if it were somehow possible to do that using another method.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that you can use the following command ...

```
SqlDatabase dbEngine = new SqlDatabase(connectionString);
```

not quite as versatile as the Database object but it works for my purpose.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

It's solved my problem. I have a single web app using many database, according to the different subdomain in the url to connect to the different database. such as:

---

- abc.test.com ------>using the   Db_projectABC
- def.test.com   ------>using the db_ProjectDEF

---

I use url-rewrite to parse the subdomain name, and use the subdomain name to chose it's database connection string which stored in the main database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Database objDatabase = new Microsoft.Practices.
                    EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql.SqlDatabase(@"Password=mypassword;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Data Source=192.168.2.1"); 
      // Data Sourc is Your DB Name for ex : systemIp\\SqlExpress

            DbConnection objCon = objDatabase.CreateConnection();
            objCon.Open();
            objDbTransaction = objCon.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
            DbCommand cmd = objDatabase.GetSqlStringCommand(" Select sName from Emp");

            SqlDataReader dr = (SqlDataReader)objDatabase.ExecuteReader(cmd, objDbTransaction);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                sb.Append(Convert.ToString(dr[0]));
                sb.Append("  ");
            }
            objDbTransaction.Commit();
            objCon.Close();

            //objDatabase.DbProviderFactory.
            return sb.ToString();
```