# How to obtain app.config of a different application and modify it

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

I have two windows application. eg ., FormA and FormB

The app.config of FormA is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<configuration>

  <appSettings>

    <add key="company" value="DSRC"/>

    </appSettings>

<connectionStrings>

<add name="test" connectionString="Testing Connection String"/>

</connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Now I have another application named as Form B.

I want to retrieve both appsettings and connectionstrings of Form A into Form B.

Further I should be able to modify both of these appsettings and connection strings and save it into the Form A.

I know how to retrieve the appsettings , and connection strings of the same application and modify.

But how do I obtain of some other application and modify the same.

Kindly do let me know.

Actually I have 4 windows services running under one setup., one webservice and one wcf service and one application.
All these  have different app.configs, comprising of different appsettings and different connection strings.
I am supposed to create a windows application that will retrieve each of these settings and then save it accordingly.

I tried upto this level

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap filename= new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = @"D:\Home\FormA\FormA\bin\Debug\FormA.exe.config";


Configuration config =
   ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(filename,
   ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

But then just got struck, I just do not know how to proceed further (Sounds dumb right !)

Can anyone help me proceed down the way.

Regards
cmrhema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap2 
                = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            fileMap2.ExeConfigFilename = @"OtherFile";

            Configuration config2 =
              ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            ConnectionStringSettings newSettings = 
                config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["oldSConString"];

            ConnectionStringsSection csSection 
                = config2.ConnectionStrings;

            csSection.ConnectionStrings.Add(newSettings);                
            config2.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

**[VS2005 C# Programmatically change connection string contained in app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63546/vs2005-c-programmatically-change-connection-string-contained-in-app-config)**

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to open the configuration for that other executable something like this:

```
// full path to other EXE, including EXE extension - but *NOT* .config !!
string otherExePath = @"C:\........\OtherApp\bin\Debug\OtherApp.exe";
Configuration otherConfig = 
              ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(otherExePath);
```

and then you can access all the settings on the new `otherConfig` configuration:

```
string otherSetting = otherConfig.AppSettings.Settings["TestSetting1"].Value;
```

and you can also save it back (provided you have the necessary permissions to that directory).

```
otherConfig.Save():
```

Comment: this doesn't getting user settings from another application